# BigQuery Export Multiple Files After Query Result

Tags: bash, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with two main columns as the following:

```
Name,City
John,NY
Mike,NY
Spencer,LA
```

I would like to export multiple files (a file that contains all the Names for each City).

In the previous example, i would get two files named **NY** and **LA** with the names of every person related to them.

I know that in order to export a file from BigQuery, i need to store the data in a specific table.

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically store every list of Names grouped by Cities in a table named as the corresponding City.

If it is possible, i will create a loop in bash (using `bq ls dataset`) in order to create a file from every City table.

Is it the right way to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use clustering approach in BigQuery.

You can create a new clustered table based on your main table as:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
  'CREATE TABLE dataset.clustered_table
   CLUSTER BY city 
   AS
   select distinct name, city from `dataset.maintable`'
```

Once you have this clustered table, you can now utilize your bash script to loop over each city and query its corresponding cluster and pipe its output locally.

For example:

```
bq query --format=csv --max_rows=999999 --use_legacy_sql=false\
  "select name from dataset.clustered_table where city = 'NY'" > NY.csv
```

Note that the above query *does not* scan the entire table, and you only pay for scanning rows that are determined to be part of a specific cluster you are querying.